# Trouble reading file in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, file, visual-studio-2013, io

I can't seem to read this file using Visual Studio 2013. Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
    string buffer1, buffer2;
    int column = 1;

    ifstream fin;
    ofstream fout;
    fin.open("Airports.csv");
    if (fin.fail()){
        cerr << "Input file fail" << "\n";
        exit(-1);
    }

}
```

Every time I try to run the program, I get "Input file fail". I'm not sure where to place my "Airports.csv" file in relation to my project's file directory. The project is called "ArrayBag". So far, I have "Airports.csv" placed under:
"Z:\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ArrayBag\ArrayBag". Any tips on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The file's path is relative to executable's path. That'd be either the `Debug` or `Release` subdirectories depending on what you chose to build your application.

Comment: How do I know which build I am using?

Comment: It's a drop-down list in VS's UI. Depending on you preferences of how the UI looks.

Comment: [Behold the screenshot of my UI in combination with Paint](http://imgur.com/DtaJx0l).

Comment: @Brian - Does my answer fit what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

If you are including the file in your project for testing purposes, just added it to the project in Visual Studio and set the build action to Copy Always or Copy If Newer. Then, you can use something like this to find it:

```
int main()
{
    string buffer1, buffer2;
    int column = 1;

    ifstream fin;
    ofstream fout;
    string fullPath = System.IO.Path.Combine( 
                        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, 
                        "Airports.csv");
    fin.open(fullPath);
    if (fin.fail())
    {
        cerr << "Input file fail" << "\n";
        exit(-1);
    }
}
```

This way it doesn't care where you are building to. The file will follow your binaries.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I appreciate it. I'm having trouble understanding it, mostly because I'm new to Visual Studio. I'm going to read up on some stuff on Visual Studio before I attempt your solution - although for me my preferred solution is to place the file in the correct folder instead of adding more code to my .cpp file

Comment: Sorry. My method was C# (doh! I should've noticed your syntax). The idea is the same, though. You want to retrieve your application's path, or whatever you're wanting to use as a data path (such as %AppData%\YourAppName), and then append the filename to it. Your original code assumes the file is in the same location as the binaries, which it is not. Even when deployed, assuming the code will work in the same place is not reliable. Anyone can change the working directory through an application shortcut and such.

Comment: Also, to place the file in the "correct" folder, adding the file to your project and deploying it would make sure it's in the same path as the build. You will always need to add code to determine data paths instead of assuming the working directory. You can declare such paths once and reuse them where needed.